# Display an SQLite BLOB as an image in a WPF autogenerated data grid

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, wpfdatagrid

What I'm ultimately looking to achieve is to dynamically create the contents of the data grid from the query results that are derived from the choices the user selects on my 'form' (which happens perfectly fine); however, the very first field needs to be the image representation of its respective BLOB field in the database.

(The parenthesized ellipses added in place of user-defined criteria in order to shorten the visual query)

```
string sqliteq = "SELECT CAST(images.icon AS TEXT) AS ficon, fruits.id (, ... ) FROM images, fruits WHERE images.id = fruits.icon ( AND ... )";
```

images table structure: (Each unique BLOB is 1 of 3,000 800-byte imported .PNGs. )

```
id      INT     Primary Key
icon    BLOB
```

fruits table structure: (Contains ~100 fields)

```
id      INT     Primary Key
icon    INT
...
```

I'm unsure if what I'm trying to accomplish is better served by intercepting the specific fields as they are being created upon display:

```
SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();

                try
                {
                    da.Fill(ds);
                    dataGridView2.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
                }
```

or if I should manually apply a template within an event handler:

```
    private void dataGridView2_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        if ( ...
```

I admit that I'm unsure of the best route to take as well as how to go about fulfilling that route as I've somewhat blindly tried what I thought would work to no avail.

I would however be pleased as punch for some insight.